# Visual studio printing range within array

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

Blob is defined as follows:

```
unsigned char* blob=new unsigned char[64];
```

We then try using the immediate window

```
blob+12
0x084F8854
    *blob+12: 0x75 'u'
blob+13
0x084F8855
    *blob+13: 0x11 ''
blob+14
0x084F8856
    *blob+14: 0x94 ''
blob+12,3
0x084F8854
    [0]: 0x75 'u'
    [1]: 0x0 ''
    [2]: 0x0 ''
```

Why doesn't blob+12,3 display the 3 values for blob 12? What is it doing instead?

Comment: It's definitely a bug in the managed debugger, also present in VS2010.  Editing the value actually works, it just displays the wrong value.  You can report the bug at connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, "blob,20" works, but "blob+0,20" does not.

My best guess is it's a bug of managed expressions evaluator. If you look in MSDN, they go in length about how these things don't work and those things don't work. It could be that, in the twisted mind of the evaluator, blob+12 constitutes a 1-element array of type char, therefore elements beyond the first can't be displayed.

Comment: sweet, it even works in the GUI (blob,20) displays the first 20 bytes of an array. sweet!

Answer (score 0):

The language is C++. He has defined an unsigned char array and watching the variable values using the immediate window. The array name is blob. I tried on VS2008, I verified with a char pointer. when you say blob+12,3.., it is converted to (blob+12)[0],(blob+12)[1],(blob+12)[2]..which is essentially same as blob+13,blob+14 and blob+15 and soon.

Comment: Works exactly as described on VS2005 in managed mode (but not in native mode). You can also put "blob+12,3" into the watch window and it will show zeros there too. Weird. May be a Visual Studio bug.